# Proof of $|z_{n+1} - z_n| \leq q^{n-1}|z_2-z_1|$ via induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, induction

Let $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $q < 1$ so that

$$|z_{n+2} - z_{n+1}| \leq q|z_{n+1}-z_n|$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

How can one prove that

$$|z_{n+1} - z_n| \leq q^{n-1}|z_2-z_1|$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that the sequence converges?

This is what I have so far:

Let $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ with the characteristics that $|z_{n+1} -z_n| \leq q^n$

My hypothesis is that $\forall z,l \in \mathbb{N}: |z_{n+l} - z_n| \leq q^n(\sum_{k=0}^{l-k}q^k)$

Let $z \in \mathbb{N}$. We prove the hypothesis by induction over $l \in \mathbb{N}$.

In case $l = 1$ we get the exact characteristics of the sequence $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}:$ It is $|z_{n+1}-z_n| \leq q^n = q^n \big (\sum_{k=0}^0 q^k \big ).$

Let now $l$ be random/arbitrary and given the hypothesis for $l$ we now show it for $l+1$. Because of the triangle inequality it holds that

$$|z_{n+l+1}-z_n| \leq |z_{n+l+1}-z_{n+l}| + |z_{n+l}-z_n| $$

According to the hypothesis (which we use for the index $n+l$ instead of $n$) it follows that

$$|z_{n+l+1} - z_{n+l}| \leq q^{n+l} = q^nq^l$$

With that the first addend has been estimated. For the second one we use the induction hypothesis and get

$$|z_{n+l+1}-z_{n+l}| + |z_{n+l}-z_n| \leq q^n q^l+q^n \big (\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}q^k \big ) = q^n \big (q^l + \sum_{k=0}^{l-1}q^k \big ) = q^n \big (\sum_{k=0}^{(l+1)-1} q^k \big ) $$

Hence it is $|z_{n+l+1} - z_n| \leq q^n \big (\sum_{k=0}^{(l+1)-1} q^k\big)$ which we wanted to prove.

I feel like this proof is incomplete or wrong (convergence missing too). Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Isn't the first inequality  just a reindexing of the second inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very nearly there. What you want to show is that the sequence is Cauchy, so write out that definition and verify.

**Hint:** For $m,l > n$, show that

> $$|z_m - z_l | \leq \frac{q^n}{1-q}$$